# Can't find structs in a C++ set

Tags: c++, iterator, set, find, c++17

I'm writing a set that contains some structs for a 3d graphics program. One of the things I'm trying to do is find if one of the structs is in a set to operate with that knowledge. Here's a mwe:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

class Malla3D
{
public:
    int id;
};

struct Objeto
{
    Malla3D * modelo;
    bool operator  < (const Objeto & otro) const;
    bool operator == (const Objeto & otro) const;
};

bool Objeto :: operator < (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return this < &otro;
}

bool Objeto :: operator == (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return modelo == otro.modelo;
}

int main ()
{
    std::set<Objeto> objetos;

    Malla3D * malla1 = new Malla3D({1});
    Malla3D * malla2 = new Malla3D({2});
    Malla3D * malla3 = new Malla3D({3});
    Malla3D * malla4 = new Malla3D({4});

    Objeto objeto1({malla1});
    Objeto objeto2({malla2});
    Objeto objeto3({malla3});
    Objeto objeto4({malla4});

    objetos.insert(objeto1);
    objetos.insert(objeto2);
    objetos.insert(objeto3);
    objetos.insert(objeto4);

    for (auto it = objetos.cbegin(); it != objetos.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << "Item in set: " << (*it).modelo->id << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto1) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 1." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 1." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto2) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 2." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 2." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto3) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 3." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 3." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto4) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 4." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 4." << std::endl;

    delete malla1;
    delete malla2;
    delete malla3;
    delete malla4;
}
```

```
~
➜ g++ -g -Wall -Wextra -Wpedantic -std=c++17 mwe.cpp

~ 
➜ ./a.out
Item in set: 1
Item in set: 2
Item in set: 3
Item in set: 4
Couldn't find 1.
Couldn't find 2.
Couldn't find 3.
Couldn't find 4.
```

So, basically, two `Objeto`s are the same if their `modelo`s point to the same memory address. That way, I can ditch the `id` member data from the `Malla3D` class. I've tested the `operator ==` with gdb and it works as intended, so I don't understand why `find` can't return other than `end()`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Equivalence of a set's members is determined by its ordering relation – which is `operator<` by default – not by `==`.

Comment: @molbdnilo I don't understand how that works then. How can I know if an element is equal to one in a set?

Comment: `std::set` is ordered, Two elements `a` and `b` are equivalent if and only if `!(a < b) && !(b < a)`– that is, if neither is ordered before the other. (Equivalence is a weaker relation than equality.)

Answer (score 0):

Your operators are comparing object pointers, not member values.  When you `insert()` an `Objeto` object into the `std::set`, a *copy* is stored.  When you then try to `find()` a `Objeto` object later, the `this` pointers that are being compared by your `operator<` won't be what you are expecting (`std::set` does not use `operator==` for comparisons), hence why matches are not found.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Malla3D
{
    int id;

    bool operator  < (const Malla3D & otro) const;
    bool operator == (const Malla3D & otro) const;
};

bool Malla3D :: operator < (const Malla3D & otro) const
{
    return id < otro.id;
}

bool Malla3D :: operator == (const Malla3D & otro) const
{
    return id == otro.id;
}

struct Objeto
{
    Malla3D modelo;
    bool operator  < (const Objeto & otro) const;
    bool operator == (const Objeto & otro) const;
};

bool Objeto :: operator < (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return modelo < otro.modelo;
}

bool Objeto :: operator == (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return modelo == otro.modelo;
}

int main ()
{
    std::set<Objeto> objetos;

    Objeto objeto1{1};
    Objeto objeto2{2};
    Objeto objeto3{3};
    Objeto objeto4{4};

    objetos.insert(objeto1);
    objetos.insert(objeto2);
    objetos.insert(objeto3);
    objetos.insert(objeto4);

    for (auto it = objetos.cbegin(); it != objetos.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << "Item in set: " << it->modelo.id << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto1) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 1." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 1." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto2) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 2." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 2." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto3) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 3." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 3." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto4) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 4." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 4." << std::endl;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/Yfydu9)

Or, if you really need to use `Malla3D*` pointers in `Objeto` (why?):

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <set>

struct Malla3D
{
    int id;

    bool operator  < (const Malla3D & otro) const;
    bool operator == (const Malla3D & otro) const;
};

bool Malla3D :: operator < (const Malla3D & otro) const
{
    return id < otro.id;
}

bool Malla3D :: operator == (const Malla3D & otro) const
{
    return id == otro.id;
}

struct Objeto
{
    Malla3D* modelo;
    bool operator  < (const Objeto & otro) const;
    bool operator == (const Objeto & otro) const;
};

bool Objeto :: operator < (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return *modelo < *(otro.modelo);
}

bool Objeto :: operator == (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return *modelo == *(otro.modelo);
}

int main ()
{
    std::set<Objeto> objetos;

    Malla3D * malla1 = new Malla3D{1};
    Malla3D * malla2 = new Malla3D{2};
    Malla3D * malla3 = new Malla3D{3};
    Malla3D * malla4 = new Malla3D{4};
    
    Objeto objeto1{malla1};
    Objeto objeto2{malla2};
    Objeto objeto3{malla3};
    Objeto objeto4{malla4};

    objetos.insert(objeto1);
    objetos.insert(objeto2);
    objetos.insert(objeto3);
    objetos.insert(objeto4);

    for (auto it = objetos.cbegin(); it != objetos.cend(); ++it)
        std::cout << "Item in set: " << it->modelo->id << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto1) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 1." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 1." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto2) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 2." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 2." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto3) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 3." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 3." << std::endl;

    if (objetos.find(objeto4) != objetos.cend())
        std::cout << "Found 4." << std::endl;
    else
        std::cout << "Couldn't find 4." << std::endl;

    delete malla1;
    delete malla2;
    delete malla3;
    delete malla4;
}
```

[Demo](https://ideone.com/LbQXr4)

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. As I understand, the struct that is copied in the set is the highest level one right? It's copy should reference the same memory address so ==ing the pointers should return true. I understand it can be done with the id attribute, but I'd like to try to just reference the memory address. I also need to use the pointers because the structure is polymorphic, so that's why I'm trying to use that and get rid of the id in the first place (I didn't specify it in the op, sorry for the confusion).

Comment: I also changed Malla3D to a class. The mwe is the same but I'm a mess. Sorry one more time for this poorly written question :/

Comment: "*the struct that is copied in the set is the highest level one right?*" - I'm not sure I understand what you are saying. "*It's copy should reference the same memory address so ==ing the pointers should return true*" - yes, but as I said, `std::set` does not use `operator==` to compare elements, it uses `operator<` instead, and in that operator, `this` is pointing at a copy, not an original. "*I also need to use the pointers because the structure is polymorphic*" - then I suggest you define a virtual method that performs object comparisons via polymorphism, and not compare raw pointers at all

Comment: "*I also changed Malla3D to a class*" - makes no difference in this situation.  `struct` and `class` are treated identical, the *only* difference between them is `class` uses `private` visibility by default, while `struct` uses `public` instead.

Answer (score 0):

As molbdnilo said, I just need to use the `operator <` for the program to work correctly.

The solution: remove the `operator ==` and rewrite the other to the following:

```
bool Objeto :: operator < (const Objeto & otro) const
{
    return modelo < otro.modelo;
}
```

This way, the memory addresses are ordered and can be matched with `find`. It's an unsatisfying solution to a very dumb problem, but I learnt a lot thanks to Remy.